# Ionic - Set On-Swipe-Right on a checkbox in a list

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-build

I have a view that consists of a list of names that can be toggle 'on' and 'off' using a check box component.

This view looks like the following:
[image: Ionic Screenshot]

This works great, but I need a way for the user to be able to delete one of the list items as well. I imagined doing this with a `swipe-right` and updated my markup to be the following:

```
<ion-view view-title="Home" hide-nav-bar="true">
  <ion-content class="padding">
    <label class="item item-input">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" ng-model="model.name">
    </label>
    <button class="ion-plus-circled button-block btn-primary button" ng-click="add(model.name)" side="right">
       Add Name
    </button>
    <ion-list type="card" can-swipe="true">
      <ion-checkbox ng-repeat="participant in participants"
                      ng-model="participant.include" 
                      ng-change="participantIncludeChanged(participant.id)"
                      ng-checked="participant.include"
                      on-swipe-right="onSwipeRight(participant.id)">
          <p>{{ participant.name }}</p>
        </ion-checkbox>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

You will notice the `on-swipe-right` attribute on the `ion-checkbox` element. I would think this still works, but It does not hit the event handler (which currently just alerts the id)

How can I get the `on-swipe-right` handler to hit?

Feel free to comment on a better way of accomplishing this as well if anything comes to mind.

Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely, `ng-repeat` create a child scope for each item in the loop.

Try accessing parent scope inside the loop. `$parent.onSwipeRight(participant.id)`

`<ion-checkbox ng-repeat="participant in participants"
                      ng-model="participant.include" 
                      ng-change="participantIncludeChanged(participant.id)"
                      ng-checked="participant.include"
                      on-swipe-right="$parent.onSwipeRight(participant.id)">
    <p>{{ participant.name }}</p>
</ion-checkbox>`
 
Following link will also help you

[ng-click doesnt work inside ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736804/ng-click-doesnt-work-inside-ng-repeat)

HTH