# Sprangular ng-change property in dropdown variant

Tags: angularjs

i'm trying to change the sprangular variant selection(using button) to selecet option,

but i got stuck using angular directive to change selected value (i'm tried ng-change, ng-selected), i think my mistake in directives property,

this my wrong HTML code :

```
<select class="form-control select-styled"ng-change="selectValue(item.value)" ng-model="item.value">
<option ng-repeat="item in option.values">{{item.value.presentation}}</option></select>
```

i'm trying to use ng-click like this

```
<select class="form-control select-styled">
<option ng-repeat="item in option.values" ng-click="selectValue(item.value)">{{item.value.presentation}}</option>
```

but it's only working on Firefox, not on safari,chrome.

this is the variantSelection.coffe code

```
'use strict'

Sprangular.directive 'variantSelection', ->
  restrict: 'E'
  templateUrl: 'directives/variant_selection.html'
  scope:
    product: '='
    variant: '='
    class: '='
    change: '&'
  controller: ($scope) ->
    $scope.values = {}

$scope.$watch 'variant', (newVariant, oldVariant)->
  $scope.change({oldVariant: oldVariant, newVariant: newVariant}) if newVariant != oldVariant

$scope.isValueSelected = (value) ->
  $scope.values[value.option_type_id]?.id == value.id

$scope.isValueAvailable = (value) ->
  $scope.product.availableValues(_.values($scope.values))

$scope.selectValue = (value) ->
  $scope.values[value.option_type_id] = value
  $scope.variant = $scope.product.variantForValues(_.values($scope.values))

  link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
    scope.values = {}

if scope.variant
  for value in scope.variant.option_values
    scope.values[value.option_type_id] = value
```

Comment: you have missed ng-model binding into select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(the problem in sprangular while change variant selection into a dropdown)
using an ng-model and ng-change...
and the problem is the json not an objct

like this code :

```
<select class="form-control select-styled" ng-model="item" ng-change="selectValue(item)">
<option ng-repeat="item in option.values" value="{{ item.value }}">{{item.value.presentation}}</option></select>
```

and editing the variantSelection.coffee

```
$scope.selectValue = (value) ->
  obj = JSON.parse(value) //add this one into selectValue function
  $scope.values[obj.option_type_id] = obj
  $scope.variant = $scope.product.variantForValues(_.values($scope.values))
```

and selected select option will work in every browser..

hope this usefull for others who have the same problem with me..

sorry #RIPenglish

Answer (score 1):

In [angular document](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) you can see as like a example from the section **Using ngRepeat to generate select options**

**HTML:**

```
    <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <form name="myForm">
    <label for="repeatSelect"> Repeat select: </label>
    <select name="repeatSelect" ng-change="selectValue(data.repeatSelect)" id="repeatSelect" ng-model="data.repeatSelect">
      <option ng-repeat="option in data.availableOptions" value="{{option.id}}">{{option.name}}</option>
    </select>
  </form>
  <hr>
  <tt>repeatSelect = {{data.repeatSelect}}</tt><br/>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
    angular.module('ngrepeatSelect', [])
 .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   $scope.data = {
    repeatSelect: null,
    availableOptions: [
      {id: '1', name: 'Option A'},
      {id: '2', name: 'Option B'},
      {id: '3', name: 'Option C'}
    ],
   };
}]);
```

```js
// Code goes here

angular.module('ngrepeatSelect', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
      repeatSelect: null,
      availableOptions: [{
        id: '1',
        name: 'Option A'
      }, {
        id: '2',
        name: 'Option B'
      }, {
        id: '3',
        name: 'Option C'
      }],
    };

    $scope.selectValue = function(value) {
      console.log(value);
      alert(value);
    };
  }]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ngrepeatSelect">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.7" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <form name="myForm">
      <label for="repeatSelect"> Repeat select: </label>
      <select name="repeatSelect" id="repeatSelect" ng-model="data.repeatSelect" ng-change="selectValue(data.repeatSelect)">
        <option ng-repeat="option in data.availableOptions" value="{{option.id}}">{{option.name}}</option>
      </select>
    </form>
    <hr />
    <tt>repeatSelect = {{data.repeatSelect}}</tt>
    <br />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736804/ng-click-doesnt-work-inside-ng-repeat) where they can try to solve this problem. Thanks.

This code working only firefox and IE

```
<option ng-click="this.$parent.selectValue(data.repeatSelect)" ng-repeat="option in data.availableOptions" value="{{option.id}}">{{option.name}}</option>
```

Comment: thx mr.shohel for the answer..


ya, i also think that i wrong binding the ng-model..
based on my code what should i write in the property of ng-model ? which one is represents the data.repeatSelect?

Comment: need another property to your $scope. liek $scope.selectedValue will give you selected item of dropdown.

Comment: an empety scope ?

$scope.selectedValue = {},

then in my ng-model="option.selectedValue()" is it ?

Comment: thx mr shohel for your kindest to answer my question,, 

at least i found the way... with parse the json into an object... :D

Comment: I have spend many times for your problem. will you give me the solution? and vote me for my small contribution.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<select class="form-control select-styled">
<option ng-repeat="item in option.values" ng-click="selectValue(item.value)">{{item.value.presentation}}</option>
```

ngRepeat is a directive.
So it has own $score.

Comment: thx user5488195,
yeah that what i've tried before, but that's only working on firefox and ie(maybe), not on chrome and safari..