# ng-click not updating value in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This is the code:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in products">
    <div class=edit ng-click="dataUI.showEdit = true; content = data;">
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="renew in data.renewed">
        <div class=edit ng-click="dataUI.showEdit = true; content = renew;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal" ng-show="dataUI.showEdit">
    <div class="product_price">{{content.product_price}}</div>
</div>
```

When I click this, the popup opens but, the `content` is not filled with `items`. In the popup, I am using `content` to show the data.

What am I doing wrong here?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/22082/

Comment: Post a fully sufficient, independent question

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: The value for your ng-repeat attribute should be enclosed in quotes - is this a typo?

Comment: Yeah, that was a typo. Fixed.

Comment: Updated with JSFiddle

Comment: There are a number of things wrong here. You need to add ng-app, build a controller, your trying to use ng-repeat on an object not a collection. Give me a minute and I will mess with the fiddler.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your fiddle fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/masa671/xtaa9gev/

You were using an old version of Angular, changed to version 1.4.8 (see the JavaScript Gear).

Then, a couple of missing injections:

```
MyCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);
```

Finally, assignment to `content` in `ng-click` did not work, because `ng-repeat` creates a new scope ("Always use a dot"). I fixed this with `dataUI.content`. Here is one good explanation: [Ng-click doesn't work inside ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736804/ng-click-doesnt-work-inside-ng-repeat).

Comment: You beat me to it :-)

Comment: Sorry, I finalized my answer just 3 mins after your comment and saw it after posting my answer :-)