# ng-click is not working on ion-list using ion-reorder

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Hi i am new to ionic and angular. onclick of ion-item i need an index and i want to show accordion(collapse and expand). How can i achieve that

```
 <ion-list class="ion-navicon" show-reorder="true"
      can-swipe="listCanSwipe">
        <ion-item data-ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" data-ng-click="service($index)" class="item-thumbnail-left">
          <ion-reorder-button class="ion-navicon"
                    on-reorder="moveItem(item, $fromIndex, $toIndex)">
        </ion-reorder-button>

        <div class="{{item.name}}"></div>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Below is my controller

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('reorderCtrl',
    [
            '$scope',
            function($scope) {
                $scope.moveItem = function(item, fromIndex, toIndex) {
                    $scope.items.splice(fromIndex, 1);
                    $scope.items.splice(toIndex, 0, item);
                  };

                  $scope.service= function(index){
                      console.log(index)

                  }
                  $scope.items = [{name : jai},{name : saurabh},{name : kamesh},{name : vijay},{name : ravi}];

            }])
```

Comment: What error do you get with the current code? Did you try renaming the '$scope.service' function?

Comment: yeah i tried.  And there was no error and that function is not getting called

Comment: Are the items being loaded properly? Also, could you please upload a fiddle?

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me, hopefully it'll work for you:

```
<ion-list show-reorder="true">
     <ion-item  class="enable-pointer-events" ng-re....otherGloriousStuff>
<ion-list>
```

Comment: Thank you!  Thank you!  A million times thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed that with this in the css.

```
.disable-pointer-events{
    pointer-events: all;
}
```

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the ng-repeat directive has it's own scope. That scope does not have the `service` method that you have defined.

You can use `reorderCtrl as ctrl` syntax to import the controller. This would allow you to call the method in that controller using,

`reorderCtrl.service()`

Please refer this question as well: [Ng-click doesn't work inside ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736804/ng-click-doesnt-work-inside-ng-repeat)