# Second button click doesn't work before the first one in AngularJS

Tags: html, events, button, laravel-5, angularjs-ng-click

I am having table containing rows and in one column i am having two buttons approve and reject , the problem is reject button works only after the approve button. If I click on reject button it doesn't work on first time.
this is my code.

```
      <tr ng-repeat="item in userRequests">            
                       <td style="border: 1px solid #435363;">{{$index  + 1 }}</td>
                       <td style="border: 1px solid #435363;">{{item.email_id}}</td>
                       <td ng-if="item.request_status == 0 && item.is_active == null" style="border: 1px solid #435363;">valid till: <input type="text" datepicker ng-model="validate" style="vertical-align: top;" /> <span><button type="button" style = "margin-left: 4px;margin-right: 4px;" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-click="approveUser(item.email_id,validate)">Approve</button></span>
                       <span><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-click="rejectUser(item.email_id)">Reject</button></span></td>
     </tr>
```

i am not able to understand which thing is stopping the button to call the function on first click.
[please see the pic by clicking here the view of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8DON.png)

Comment: can you put console.log inside the function approveUser and reject user and comment the rest of the functionality and check if it is called ? , i believe the issue is in the functionality not this code

Comment: actually reject button works after i click on the approve button

Comment: i know that but did you try what i suggested inorder to see if it is clicked does it respond without functionality ?

Comment: i tried ur console method but the reject doesn't get fired when clicking the reject button on the first go.

Comment: ok then check this link the second answer might help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736804/ng-click-doesnt-work-inside-ng-repeat

Comment: it doesnt seems to be working im already using right model

Comment: is too much to ask for jsfiddle or plnkr

Comment: Oh I am very sorry sir i didnt meant that im sorry if m pushing it on you i am trying to solve it though

Comment: no problem , but can you please upload your code on plnr or jsfiddle in order for me to try solve the issue

Comment: here if it could help https://jsfiddle.net/s0nxj9vt/6/

Answer (score 0):

first your fiddle has issues so i changed used another one 
check this fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/32109/

it is working. i also tried it on angular seed project and there was no problem but you need to change registerCtrl to controller !

```
app.registerCtrl('myCtrl', function($scope, $http, $rootScope) {

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http, $rootScope) {
```