# Why does this ng-click work with a function, but not with these values?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

I have the following html:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        {{myValue}} 
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li ng-repeat="value in valueList">
            <button class="btn btn-link" ng-click="myValue = value.key">
                {{value.key}}
            </button>
        </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.valueList = [ { key: "A" }, { key: "B" } ];
$scope.myValue = $scope.valueList[0].key;
```

This returns a dropdown starting with "A" with "A" & "B" being options.

Now, the above html will NOT turn myValue into "B", when the dropped-down button is clicked. However, when I change the ng-click into `ng-click="changeValue(value.key)"` it does work as expected. Why does the `myValue = value.key` do nothing while `{{ value.key }}` shows the right things?

Function for completeness:

```
$scope changeValue = function(valueKey) { 
    $scope.myValue = valueKey 
}
```

Comment: This seems to be related to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736804/ng-click-doesnt-work-inside-ng-repeat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `ng-repeate` create new scope and `myValue` is out of scope. so if you are using `controllerAs` syntax it works correctly.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.valueList = [{
    key: "A"
  }, {
    key: "B"
  }];
  vm.myValue = vm.valueList[0].key;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl as vm">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        {{vm.myValue}} 
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li ng-repeat="value in vm.valueList">
        <button class="btn btn-link" ng-click="vm.myValue = value.key">
                {{value.key}}
            </button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I found another solution which suggests a function `$scope.getScope = function () { return $scope; }`, then turn the click into `ng-click ="getScope.myValue = value.key"` Which of these solutions would be considered "better" and why?

Comment: yes that is another solution. but using `controllerAs` syntax is better. because you are using other benefit of this syntax also.