# replacing ng-show with ng-if

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, model-view-controller

in my accordion(created directive called expander for this) i have question and yes/no drop down answers http://jsfiddle.net/xVZEX/116/

```
<expander ng-repeat="form in FormDataList.SectionList">
    <div id="{{form.SectionID}}">
        <div ng-repeat="question in form.QuestionList">
            <span>{{question.QuestionText}}</span>
            <select name="ans_{{form.SectionID}}_{{$index}}" ng-model="item" 
                    ng-change="CalculateValidationPoints(item, question, 
                    form.SectionID)" ng-options="ans as ans.AnswerText for 
                    ans in question.AnswerList">
                    <option value="">--Select--</option>
            </select>          
            <input type="text" ng-model="ExitName" 
                   ng-show="name_{{question.QuestionID}}.show" 
                   placeholder="Name"/>
            <input type="text" ng-model="ExitTitle" 
            ng-show="name_{{question.QuestionID}}.show" placeholder="Title"/>
        </div>
    </div>  
</expander>
```

I am displaying 20 questions. User can choose yes/no for answer for each question and move to next. The last question needs user to fill in their Name and Title if he/she choose yes. if for last question user chooses no then Name and Title is not needed. 
To achieve this I have added two inputs ExitName and ExitTitle with NG-show in my expander and in my controller I show and hide my inputs for the question

```
if (question.QuestionText === "Was exit conference conducted?" && selectedAnswer.AnswerText === "Yes") {

        var propName = "name_" + selectedAnswer.QuestionID;
        var propTitle = "title_" + selectedAnswer.QuestionID;

        $rootScope[propName] = {
            show: true
        };
        $scope[propName] = $rootScope[propName];
        $rootScope[propTitle] = {
            show: true
        };
        $scope[propTitle] = $rootScope[propTitle];

        $scope.IsExit = true;
    }
    else {
        $scope.IsExit = false;
    }
```

it works perfectly. But i am not happy with this as in the DOM there will be two input  ExitName and ExitTitle for all 20 question only hidden. I want to replace ng-show with ng-if.

how can I change my code to make ng-if work.

**Edit--------**

So for testing i created an input

```
<input type="text" ng-if="name_{{question.QuestionID}}.show"/>
```

in my expander now as you suggested i chaged this inmy controller

```
if (question.QuestionText === "Was exit conference conducted?" && selectedAnswer.AnswerText === "Yes") {
        var vm = this;
        var propName = "name_" + selectedAnswer.QuestionID;
        var propTitle = "title_" + selectedAnswer.QuestionID;

        vm[propName] = {
            show: true
        };

    }
    else {
        vm[propName] = {
            show: false
        };
    }
```

does not work

Comment: does changing  ng-show="name_{{question.QuestionID}}.show" to  ng-if="name_{{question.QuestionID}}.show"  not work?

Comment: no it does not. i tried but cannot access show

Comment: this issue is very popular. because `ng-repeat` create new `scope` so for this you should use `controllerAs` syntax. so use `var vm = this;` instead `$scope`

Comment: @Hadi can you please elaborate I am very new to angular to be prcide ny 2nd months of using angular js. an example will be apprecialted

Comment: please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45593879/why-does-this-ng-click-work-with-a-function-but-not-with-these-values/45594015#45594015)

Comment: try to get it back to the right scope with `ng-if="name_{{$parent.question.QuestionID}}.show"`

Comment: @Hadi  please check the edits

Comment: @AlekseySolovey please check the edits

Comment: can you create a demo?

Comment: @Hadi i have created http://jsfiddle.net/xVZEX/115/

Comment: @Hadi sorry i had sedn you the wrong link http://jsfiddle.net/xVZEX/116/