# Pass Ng Repeat value to ng click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I cant pass a value to form the ng-repeat to the ng-click in my angular aplication.

This is my html

```
        <div ng-repeat="x in tt" >
           <div>
                <div ng-hide={{x.quien!=dameLocal.nombre}}>
                    <a href ng-click="edit(x.id)">
                       <i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-2x ' ></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

But the *edit(x.id)* dont recive any value.
 inspecting the code, i get this:

```
<a href="" ng-click="edit(x.id)">
```

so, why i dont get the id value in the ng-click?

Thanks in advance

Edit:
If i put for example a

`data-id={{x.id}}`
it get the x.id value, so what gives?

edit2:

Here is my Js:

```
    $scope.edit=function(a){
    console.log(a);
    // $scope.comentEdit(a);
    // $scope.comentDel(a);
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide your JavaScript.
You might want to take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736804/ng-click-doesnt-work-inside-ng-repeat

Comment: This should be working correctly, can you add a text value between the <a> tags and see if it displays as expected?

Comment: Unable to reproduce the problem. The value is being correctly passed in this [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/9jazLJlg7lLqZUsTV4N5?p=preview).

Comment: But i'm closing this question because now its working.
All i did was close the laptop and take a nap.
And now it's working.
So all i got to blame, is cache or some software goblin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This id will send to your function edit(). Put a breakPoint in dev tools in edit function and you will see this id in it.

```
$scope.edit = function(id) {
    console.log(id);
};
```

Your data tt should be like this in that case:

```
$scope.tt = [
    {
        id: "123",
        name: "item"
    }
];
```